# SDL_BlitSurface doesn't work - I can't see the image on my surface

Tags: c++, image, window, sdl

Once again stuck with some code that I can't just figure out how to make work. I am trying to create a SDL surface, load a bitmap image and display it. My code is something like this:

```
struct Image {
    string       Name;
    SDL_Surface* Surface;
};

int WinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE hPrevInst, PSTR lpCmdL, INT nCmdS) {
    // Will store our bitmap
    Image NewImage;

    // Initialization
    SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_EVERYTHING);

    // Create main window
    SDL_Surface *Window = SDL_SetVideoMode(640,480,32,SDL_HWSURFACE|SDL_DOUBLEBUF);
    SDL_WM_SetCaption("MyApp", "MyApp");

    // Load image and make it compatible
    SDL_Surface* Surf_Temp = NULL;
    if((Surf_Temp = SDL_LoadBMP("myimage.bmp")) != NULL) {
        NewImage.Name = "MyImage";
        NewImage.Surface = SDL_DisplayFormat(Surf_Temp);
        SDL_FreeSurface(Surf_Temp);
    }

    // Draw image over the window
    if (NewImage.Surface != NULL && Window  != NULL) {
        SDL_Rect DestR;
                 DestR.x = 0;
                 DestR.y = 0;
        if (SDL_BlitSurface(NewImage.Surface, NULL, Window, &DestR) == -1) {
            MessageBox(NULL, "Error", "Alert", MB_OK);
        }
    }

    // Run
    SDL_Event Event;
    while(!End) {
        while(SDL_PollEvent(&Event)) {
            EventsHandler(&Event);
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Well, the image is loaded correctly. I verified it by getting the NewImage.Surface->w (width), which is the correct bitmap's width. I don't get any error message (SDL_BlitSurface returns 0), so I don't know why the window is still black, no image displayed.

Comment: Check your BMP format please, is it 24 or 32 bit?

Comment: It is 24 bit, and as I said, at least, SDL_LoadBMP gets its width and height correctly

Comment: Convert your BMP to 32 bit and it should work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to call [SDL_Flip](http://sdl.beuc.net/sdl.wiki/SDL_Flip) to update the screen after you blit to it.

```
SDL_Flip(Window);
```

Read about [double buffering](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiple_buffering) also.

Comment: Nice one, i totally didn't think about something that obvious.

Comment: I knew something like that was missing. Thanks